# Erro ao enviar NFe

Tags: c#, web-service, nfe, wsdl

Estou tentando emitir NFe utilizando o webservice do SEFAZ RS, porém esta gerando alguns erros quando chamo o método `nfeAutorizacaoLote`.
Parece que o erro está na configuração do webservice.

Ao referenciar a [URL](https://nfe-homologacao.sefazrs.rs.gov.br/ws/NfeAutorizacao/NFeAutorizacao.asmx) pelo Visual Studio, é criado a seguinte configuração no arquivo `web.config`:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="https://nfe-homologacao.sefazrs.rs.gov.br/ws/NfeAutorizacao/NFeAutorizacao.asmx" 
        binding="basicHttpBinding" 
        bindingConfiguration="NfeAutorizacaoSoap" 
        contract="NFeAutorizacao.NfeAutorizacaoSoap" 
        name="NfeAutorizacaoSoap" />
    </client>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="NfeAutorizacaoSoap">
                <security mode="Transport" />
            </binding>
            <binding name="NfeAutorizacaoSoap1" />
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

No entanto está retornando o erro abaixo, chamarei de *erro1*:

> A solicitação HTTP está proibida com o esquema de autenticação de cliente 'Anonymous'

Pelo que pesquisei, umas das possibilidades seria alterar a configuração de:
 `<security mode="Transport" />` 

para:
 `<security mode="TransportCredentialOnly"/>`

Porém, apenas retornou outro erro, chamarei de *erro2*:

> O esquema de URI do provedor 'https' é inválido; esperado 'http'.\r\nNome do parâmetro: via

Já testei todas as configurações possíveis para `mode`, e sempre retorna ou o *erro1* ou o *erro2*.
Realizei um teste paraleleo pelo [serviço de validação](https://www.sefaz.rs.gov.br/NFE/NFE-VAL.aspx) de XML e está tudo certo com o arquivo, o problema é na requisição do webservice.

Aqui está o trecho do código que faz a requisição:

```
try
{
    XmlDocument oXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    oXmlDoc.Load("c:\teste.xml");
    XmlNode oNode = oXmlDoc.DocumentElement;
    NFeAutorizacao.NfeAutorizacaoSoapClient oNfeAutorizacaoSoapClient = new NFeAutorizacao.NfeAutorizacaoSoapClient();
    NFeAutorizacao.nfeCabecMsg onfeCabecMsg = new NFeAutorizacao.nfeCabecMsg();
    onfeCabecMsg.versaoDados = "3.10";
    onfeCabecMsg.cUF = "43";
    XmlNode xmlnode = oNfeAutorizacaoSoapClient.nfeAutorizacaoLote(ref onfeCabecMsg, oNode);
}
catch (Exception exc)
{

}
```

Obs: Ao acessar a [URL](https://nfe-homologacao.sefazrs.rs.gov.br/ws/NfeAutorizacao/NFeAutorizacao.asmx), é necessário ter um certificado digital, caso contrário irá retornar acesso proibido: 
`HTTP Error 403.7 - Forbidden: The page you are attempting to access requires your browser to have a Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) client certificate that the Web server recognizes.`

Comment: Você tem um certificado válido instalado na máquina?

Comment: @LINQ, sim tenho, comprado justamente para fazer os testes!

Comment: O que aparece quando você tenta acessar a página pelo browser?

Comment: qual página? esta: https://nfe-homologacao.sefazrs.rs.gov.br/ws/NfeAutorizacao/NFeAutorizacao.asmx, se sim aparece dois métodos `nfeAutorizacaoLote` e `nfeAutorizacaoLoteZip`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

não fiz com autorização mas fica assim meu usei Nfedistribuição e recepção de evento abaixo configuração do webconfig:

```
 <binding name="RecepcaoEventoSoap">
    <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" proxyCredentialType="None"/>
    </security>
 </binding>
```

Comment: Bom dia Eduardo, você chegou a desenvolver o Donwload das xmls emitidas contra o cnpj?

Comment: consegui sim atraves do Nfedistribuição qual duvida seria?

Comment: Boa Tarde Eduardo, também consegui, caso queira dar uma olhada esta nesse link: https://github.com/thgmbz/DownloadXML-NT2014.002

Efetuei algumas alterações para melhoria do código mas esse projeto ainda é o primeiro funciona perfeitamente.
Agradeço

Comment: @ThiagoMottaBarboza ficou bom te segui la no github